# Redirection rules not working in Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've created a bucket in S3 to store images and followed [Resize Images on the Fly with Amazon S3, AWS Lambda, and Amazon API Gateway | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/resize-images-on-the-fly-with-amazon-s3-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/) to resize them using Lambda.

It is working good so far but I can't make the redirection rules work. For some reason I keep getting "No such key" when it should redirect to the REST api to resize the image.

Here is my config for the redirection rules:

```
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <KeyPrefixEquals/>
            <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <Protocol>https</Protocol>
            <HostName>8mxk2saka6.execute-api.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>default/pp-create-thumbnails-for-user-assets?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
            <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

Here is a screenshot with the error:

[image: Screenshot with the error i get when trying to access thumbnail that should be redirected to the API endpoint which generates it when it does not exist]

Adding screenshots for the API config in Lambda:

[image: Dashboard at API configuration]

And a screenshot which shows what i see in the Lambda dashboard:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Update**

As Tom says in the answer below, it is very important to notice that there are two ways to access the bucket from the browser:

```
1. https://YOUR_BUCKET.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

and the other is

```
2. http://YOUR_BUCKET.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

You will **NOT** be able to apply redirection rules to the first one, only the 2nd one is aware of them.

So, after doing the configuration to resize the images, make sure you use the 2nd url (static website hosting one) for doing redirections.

Hope this helps anyone else with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference I can see between yours and my working version is the `default/` vs `Prod/` prefix to your API trigger. To check this, go to the API gateway, select your api and then go to the dashboard. There's a link saying 'invoke your API at ...' then a URL. If that has Prod at the end you've found the problem. It is **case sensitive**. That cost me an hour or two...

```
<RoutingRules>
  <RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
      <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
      <Protocol>https</Protocol>
      <HostName>***YOUR API DOMAIN***.amazonaws.com</HostName>
      <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>Prod/***YOUR API TRIGGER***?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
      <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
  </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

I also struggled over this for a while.

Double check the name of your API trigger `pp-create-thumbnails-for-user-assets`, check the lambda logs and see if you hit it at all. If you are hitting it, then make sure that your are properly handling the `event.queryStringParameters.key` in the lambda function. If you are not hitting the lambda function then check you have set up static web site hosting as per the instructions, go to that S3 tab and copy the **endpoint**. It should be something like

> http://**YOUR_BUCKET**.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com.

If you don't use the endpoint it won't operate the redirection rule.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Tom, thank you for answering. Just added some screenshots. It says "default/" in the "Invoke...". Going to look at the logs to see if the lambda function is being called.

Comment: Also, I notice from your browser screenshot that you're not trying to access the image at the url endpoint of your bucket. If you have set up static web site hosting as per the instructions, then go to that S3 tab and copy the endpoint. It should be something like http://<YOUR_BUCKET>.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com. If you don't use the endpoint it won't operate the redirection rule

Comment: Tom, this is the one https://pp-user-assets.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/34x34/ricky.jpg that is the s3 bucket that should redirect on 404 to the API gateway

Comment: It's working at https://pp-user-assets.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/34x34/ricky.jpg

Comment: I was accessing my bucket using: https://pp-user-assets.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/ and it was NOT working, but when i use http://pp-user-assets.s3-website-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com it DOES work. Not sure really what's the difference but it is hitting the endpoint there! Notice that it works for http, not https

Comment: All's well that ends well! The difference is the s3 object address and the s3 website endpoint address. The redirection rules only work when you use the website endpoint address.

Comment: Tom, given that the static web hosting is being served over http, do you know if there are any docs to block the access to the bucket itself and specifically to the xml returned when you point to the root of it, here: https://pp-user-assets.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: New question, I think. Let me know if you post it.

Comment: Yes, :) i already found the way to do it. I'm going to answer my question now with what we discussed for future reference (any others with the same problem)

Comment: PLEASE NOTE the *HTTP* protocol. NOT https...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your ReplaceKeyPrefixWith is different. Where did you get default/pp-create-thumbnails-for-user-assets?

Comment: My API endpoint in the Lambda config is: https://8mxk2saka6.execute-api.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/pp-create-thumbnails-for-user-assets; so i set https, the hostname for it and the path, is that wrong?

Comment: In the article, the is set to the remaining part after APIGateway endPoint - host name part . I am not sure if you follow the same process.

Comment: Justin, yes, but the problem is that i believe it doesn't even match the redirection rule because otherwise i would get a different error. Just attached a screenshot, look above :)